# Azure Sentinel Threat Intelligence User Agent string

Tags: azure-sentinel

Attempting to setup this Solution Data Connector, but the connection does not use a user agent string.  Is something that can be modified?

Viewing the logs from my WAF in a SIEM, the WAF does not see a user agent string on the request.  I've looked through Azure-Sentinel repo and dont see where it gets set or not set, so assuming its a MS side "feature".  Hoping for validation and maybe some way to set the user agent string.

Answer (score 0):

few ways you can attack this

you could create a parser for your WAF logs, to accomplish this go to Microsoft Sentinel > Logs > Create a Parser, and Save as a function

you could hackery the template the Solution Data Connector was created from, to accomplish this go to the resource group where your Microsoft Sentinel lives and find the Deployments section, find the template the WAF was created from and adjust the KQL and API request there